# calculate a quarterly average, a monthly data

Tags: r, data-transformation

I'm new to R, maybe this is very simple but I don't know how to do it

I have the following data

```
x1 <- c(468491, 449743, 436815, 444523, 433937, 389958, 403446, 423921, 389624, 418591, 438288, 
        422841, 476935, 542047, 582197, 516497, 523227, 467217, 499644, 430876)

fec <- c(201201,    201202, 201203, 201204, 201205, 201206, 201207, 201208, 201209, 201210, 201211,
         201212,    201301, 201302, 201303, 201304, 201305, 201306, 201307, 201308)

Data <- as.data.frame(cbind(fec,x1))
```

I need to add 3 months and divide it by 4, and go iterating

example:

```
  data1                           data2 (with avg)

 fec     x1                              fec     x1         
1  201201 468491                     Q1'2012      sum(468491,449743,436815)/4
2  201202 449743
3  201203 436815
4  201204 444523                     Q2'2012      sum(444523,433937,389958)/4
5  201205 433937
6  201206 389958
7  201207 403446                     Q3'2012      sum(403446,423921,389624)/4
8  201208 423921
9  201209 389624
10 201210 418591                     Q4'2012      sum(418591,438288,422841)/4
11 201211 438288
12 201212 422841
13 201301 476935                     Q1'2013      sum(476935,542047,582197)/4
14 201302 542047
15 201303 582197
16 201304 516497                     Q2'2013      sum(516497,523227,467217)/4
17 201305 523227
18 201306 467217
19 201307 499644                     Q3'2013      sum(499644,430876)/2
20 201308 430876
```

please can you help me by replicating the data2 I have been trying to do it for hours but it doesn't work,or explain to me how I can do it, any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Data$year = substr(Data$fec,1,4)
Data$M = substr(Data$fec,5,6)
Data$Q = 1 + (as.numeric(Data$M)-1) %/% 3
```

You get the quarter and year:

```
head(Data)
     fec     x1 year  M Q
1 201201 468491 2012 01 1
2 201202 449743 2012 02 1
3 201203 436815 2012 03 1
4 201204 444523 2012 04 2
5 201205 433937 2012 05 2
6 201206 389958 2012 06 2
```

Then add the weights:

```
Data$weights = 0.25
if(nrow(Data)>17){
Data$weights[18:nrow(Data)] = (1/(20-(18:20 -1)))[1:(20-nrow(Data))]
}
```

Then average:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% select(year,Q,x1,weights) %>%
group_by(year,Q) %>%
summarize(x1=sum(x1*weights))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   year [2]
  year      Q      x1
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2012      1 338762.
2 2012      2 317104.
3 2012      3 304248.
4 2012      4 319930 
5 2013      1 400295.
6 2013      2 415670 
7 2013      3 310173.
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I solve the last data? not divided by 4 but by 2

Comment: ok i did not see that, you have to do that manually? Or you have to pre-define what to divide by.. which one do you prefer?

Comment: it depends on the last 3 data, if the total data has 20 rows, row 18 is divided by 3, row 19 is divided by 2, and row 20 is divided by 1

Comment: but you wrote divide by 2 in the post?

Comment: If it was my mistake sorry, check well and it must be divided from row 18 by 3 then by 2 and then by 1, 
the final data will always have 20 rows, so you could add something, that says if nrow <= 17 then divide 4, when t = 18-20 then divide (20- (t-1))

Comment: just see whether it works.. otherwise change the weights accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106790/discussion-between-redondo-and-stupidwolf).